# How do I search for entries containing a given text or regular expression using TalkBack

Tags: accessibility, search, text-editor, google-voice-actions, talk-back

I would like to know how to use TalkBack to search for entries by issuing a given partial keyword or regular expression. Perhaps, as an alternative, the user could speak an entry, and, after the text was entered, the user could check the text for correctness, by having it read aloud, letter per letter, or as a whole, and then issue the search.

This could be useful in several contexts, for instance, the blind person is coding or using some app with menus or am interface with a list of buttons and wants to get to a given menu entry without remembering its position, without getting confused by listening to other entries, which may make them forget what they're doing.

Or they may be going through the chronology of a web browser, and cannot find what they're looking for.

It would be nice if there were a way to do this, because it would really help.

Thanks.